# CoreML performance issue on M1Max about Neural Engine

Tags: swift, apple-m1, coreml

I am using a CoreML model from [RobustVideoMatting](https://github.com/PeterL1n/RobustVideoMatting).

I have an M1Macbook13 16G and an M1Max Macbook 16 64G.

When "computeUnits" using .all or default, M1Max 16 is much slower than M1 13, finish one prediction time is 0.202 and 0.155.

Using .cpuOnly, M1Max 16 is fast a little, time is 0.129 and 0.146.

Using .cpuAndGPU, M1Max 16 is much fast than M1 13, time is 0.057 and 0.086.

And when I use .all or default, M1Max will appear error messages like this:

```
H11ANEDevice::H11ANEDeviceOpen IOServiceOpen failed result= 0xe00002e2
H11ANEDevice::H11ANEDeviceOpen kH11ANEUserClientCommand_DeviceOpen call failed result=0xe00002bc
Error opening LB - status=0xe00002bc.. Skipping LB and retrying
```

But M1 13 doesn't have any errors.

So I want to know is this a bug of CoreML or M1Max?

My Codes is like this:

```
let config = MLModelConfiguration()
config.computeUnits = .all

let model = try rvm_mobilenetv3_1920x1080_s0_25_int8_ANE(configuration: config)

let image1 = NSImage(named: "test1")?.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil)
let input = try? rvm_mobilenetv3_1920x1080_s0_25_int8_ANEInput(srcWith:image1!, r1i: MLMultiArray(), r2i: MLMultiArray(), r3i: MLMultiArray(), r4i: MLMultiArray())

 _ = try? model.prediction(input: input!)
```